# How to groupby a dataframe with two level header and generate box plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by, seaborn

Now I have a dataframe like below (original dataframe):

| Equipment | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 2 | 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 | 13 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 | 14 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 | 15 | 15 |

And I want to transform the dataframe like below (transformed dataframe):

| 1 | - | - | 2 | - | - | 3 | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 14 | 14 | 14 |
| 11 | 11 | 11 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 15 | 15 | 15 |

How can I make such groupby transformation with two level header by Pandas?

Additionally, I want to use the transformed dataframe to generate box plot, and the whole box plot is divided into three parts (i.e. 1,2,3), and each part has three box plots (i.e. A,B,C). Can I use the transformed dataframe in Image 2 without any processing? Or can I realize the box plotting only by the original dataframe?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, do help us help you by posting the actual code of the dataframe rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
g = df.groupby(' Equipment ')[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).T)
```

**g:**

```
Equipment   1           2           3
            A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
          0 10  10  10  12  12  12  14  14  14
          1 11  11  11  13  13  13  15  15  15
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
grp = df.groupby(' Equipment ')[df.columns[1:]]

grp.apply(print)
```

---

```
    A    B    C 
0   10   10   10
1   11   11   11
    A    B    C 
2   12   12   12
3   13   13   13
    A    B    C 
4   14   14   14
5   15   15   15
```

you can see the index 0 1, 2 3, 4 5 for each equipment group(1,2,3).

That's why I used reset_index to make them 0 1 for each group why???

If you do without reset index:

```
df.groupby(' Equipment ')[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: x.T)
```

---

```
            0    1      2    3    4     5
Equipment                           
    1   A   10.0 11.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
        B   10.0 11.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
        C   10.0 11.0   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
    2   A   NaN  NaN    12.0 13.0 NaN   NaN
        B   NaN  NaN    12.0 13.0 NaN   NaN
        C   NaN  NaN    12.0 13.0 NaN   NaN
    3   A   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  14.0  15.0
        B   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  14.0  15.0
        C   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  14.0  15.0
```

See the values in (2,3) and (4,5) column. I want to combine them into (0, 1) column only. That's why reset index with a drop.

```
            0   1
Equipment           
    1   A   10  11
        B   10  11
        C   10  11
    2   A   12  13
        B   12  13
        C   12  13
    3   A   14  15
        B   14  15
        C   14  15
```

You can play with the code to understand it deeply. What's happening inside.

Comment: If it does can you accept it as an answer. If not let me know what are you looking for :)?